# Mercedes P2004 error code

Tags: mercedes-benz, intake-manifold, intake

I have 2007 Mercedes s550, It runs without any issues but I can see P2004 error code which says: Intake Manifold Runner control stuck open Bank 1a.
A week ago I saw a check engine light on, I plugged in ODB2 device and was able to read P2004 and P0025 (B Camshaft Position - Timing Over - Retarded Bank 2). I removed errors and Don't see check engine anymore as well as P0025. Only P2004 stays.
I did some research and I see that usually p2004 pops up when [Intake Manifold Air Flap Runner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079Y9TPRB) is broken. I checked mine and it looks fine but it's not moving when I turn on the engine. Not sure when it should move though.
Any ideas how can I troubleshoot my problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I did a Google search and came up with a pretty informative video on YouTube on this. I don't know much about this but the video seems to be informative.  https://youtu.be/ooatlAONjoA

Comment: I saw that video and I mentioned that my Intake Manifold Air Flap Runner is not broken as they say it's usually the reason of the problem.